# Download dotfile using html5 download preserving name

Tags: html, download, attributes, dotfiles

I have a directory structure, containing a list of directories and files.
I want to give user an option of downloading a file. For downloading, I'm using `HTML5 download` attribute. It works perfectly.

But the directory structure i have can have dotfiles too, examples: `.babelrc`, `.gitignore`, `.eslintrc`, etc.

When I use the same technique to download such files, file is being downloaded with the same content but the file is no longer a dotfile. After downloading, let's say `.gitignore`, the file becomes `gitignore.txt`.

I'm using this for my project **[github-plus](https://github.com/softvar/github-plus) - Chrome extension to display size of each file, download link and an option of copying it's contents**.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

I'm using this format:

`<a href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/softvar/secure-ls/master/.babelrc" title="Download File" download=".babelrc">Download</a>`

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/softvar/6ezm1pue/2/)**

Answer (score 3):

Quoting HTML5 specification on **[downloading resources](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#downloading-resources)** with the `download` attribute, about file type/extension :

> If the claimed type is known, then alter filename to add an extension corresponding to claimed type.
>
> Otherwise, if named type is known to be potentially dangerous (e.g. it will be treated by the platform conventions as a native executable, shell script, HTML application, or executable-macro-capable document) then optionally alter filename to add a known-safe extension (e.g. ".txt").

It seems that:

- the part of the algorithm that finally choses the filename is **platform-dependent**
- if the extension is not recognised, as in the case of *dotfiles*, the browser will try to determine it by using the file MIME type
- *dotfiles* might be considered anyway as **potentially harmful** as they are hidden files on various platforms. This seems to be what happens in your case, with the initial dot being removed and the `.txt` extension appended.

Comment: This is some useful information.
Isn't there any hack / workaround?

Comment: Not that I know of, and if it was the case, it could and would be considered as a leak.

Comment: is this still the case? because I am running into the same exakt "issue", and cant really believe that you as a developer cant allow dotfiles to be downloaded like any other file. Why dont they let the developer decide whether dotfiles should be downloaded as `.txt`? Any attribute like `allow-dotfiles` on an HTMLAnchorElement would do the trick.

Comment: This issue really makes it impossible to create any application where a user can upload and download files, especially when it comes to source code, because configuration files like .gitignore are pretty common; you would need a workaround like allow downloading only for directories, zip them on the server and send the zip back to the client, maybe this way the dotfiles would be preserved (i havent tried it, maybe it doesn't work).