# express downloading files with no filename and only an extension like ".gitignore" leads to FileNotFound even though path is correct and file exists

Tags: node.js, express, file, path

I am writing a simple file server to upload and download files with express@4.18.2, and Im stuck on the download part. Whenever I try to download a file that has no name, but only an extension (like `.gitignore` or `.prettierrc)` with `res.download`, I get a NotFoundError (see full error message below).
Example:

```
app.get("/download", function (req: Request, res: Response) {
    res.download("C:/Users/stadl/Desktop/File-Server/.gitignore");
});
```

results in a NotFoundError, however, the following works:

```
app.get("/download", function (req: Request, res: Response) {
    res.download("C:/Users/stadl/Desktop/File-Server/t.txt");
});
```

The file paths are both correct, and both files are existing, the directory structure looks like that:

```
C:/Users/stadl/Desktop/File-Server/
|
|
| - - - client/
| - - - server/
|          |
|          | - - - server.ts (contains the app.get("/download")... snippet)
|          . . .
| 
| - - - .gitignore
| - - - t.txt
|
. . .
```

The same happens with relative paths, (`../.gitignore` and `../t.txt`).
Is this a bug, is this intended or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allow dotfiles in the `options` object of `res.download` by setting `allow`, since it's disabled/ignored by default (the default value `ignore` sends 404):

```
res.download("C:/Users/stadl/Desktop/File-Server/.gitignore", {dotfiles:"allow"});
```

see:

> dotfiles
>
> Option for serving dotfiles. Possible values are “allow”,
> “deny”, “ignore”.

https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.download

and

> dotfiles
>
> Possible values for this option are:
>
> “allow” - No special treatment for dotfiles.
>
> “deny” - Deny a request for a dotfile, respond with 403, then call next().
>
> “ignore” - Act as if the dotfile does not exist, respond with 404, then call next().

https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#express.static

Comment: This works! However, the dot before the extension is missing on the downloaded file. So `.gitignore` becomes `gitignore`, which is pretty annoying. You would have to manually add the dot yourself. It also doesnt matter what filename I give `res.download`, it always ignores the dot if there arent any chars before it. Any way to fix that?

Comment: right. looks like not: [Download dotfile using html5 download preserving name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38931933/download-dotfile-using-html5-download-preserving-name)