# download link remove '.' (dot) from prefix and add '.txt'

Tags: javascript, typescript, file, download

I am trying to download a file from a server. I can download most files, but when I try to download a file with the prefix '.' (dot) on the name, it removes the '.' and adds '.text' as a postfix to the file name. For example, when downloading a '.bashrc' file, the filename is changed to 'bashrc.txt'.

here is response from servre
[image]

Below is my code; do you have any idea what is wrong?

```
await downloadFileFromServerAPI({
  ...details,
  connectionId: connectionId
}).then((res) => {
  debugger;
  const downloadFileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([res]));
  const downloadFileLink = document.createElement('a');
  downloadFileLink.href = downloadFileURL;
  downloadFileLink.setAttribute('download', details.name);
  downloadFileLink.click();
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.body.removeChild(downloadFileLink);
  }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download dotfile using html5 download preserving name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38931933/438273)

Comment: You can experiment using [this reproducible example in the TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mxzebw) (because Stack snippets run in `<iframe>`s where the origin is `null`)

Comment: yes @jsejcksn, your comment is helpful. This is some useful information